# NodeJS async function that wont work

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous

I read many posts on how to create async functions in NodeJS but i cant figure it out! I know this is the most asked topic, but look at this sample code here:

```
function test2(){
console.log("Check x");
}
function test(callback){
    for(var i=0;i<1000000000000;i++){}
    callback();
}

console.log("Check 1");
test(test2);
console.log("Check 2");
console.log("Check 3");
```

Now shouldnt NodeJS consider test to be a sync function !?
and if not then how do i create it so that i can reach the logging of check 2 and 3 without waiting for the loop to end ?

Comment: use `settimeout `

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything in Node.js is asynchronous.
Asynchronous process only happens when I/O or Event are involved like accessing file system, handling network request, reading data from database, etc.

Example:

```
var fs = require('fs); //node.js built-in file system which requires I/O from storage
function getDataFromFile(callback) {
  //fs.readFile is asynchronous process
  fs.readFile('path/to/file', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
     callback(data);
  });
}
getDataFromFile(function(data) {
  //this is asynchronous callback from getDataFromFile()
  console.log('data ' + data);
});
```